# Using graphical modeler script via command line

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, saga, pyqt, taudem

I have made a script through the graphical modeler and I exported it. This is the code that it exported:

[Python code] https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsIU5.jpg

How do I run this code outside of QGIS? Which libraries are needed?